# How to know which control window got focus right now in Modal dialog using Win32 API?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something with the Modal dialog in Win7. To do that I need to know which control window has got focus right now by using Win32 API. If I could know which control is now got focus then I can send message to this window to do some specific task.

Could any one suggest me how should I know which control has got focus right now using win 32?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which window has keyboard focus and you're only interested in windows belonging to your own thread use [GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294.aspx).

Finding out which window in the entire system has focus requires a few steps:

- [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx)
- [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522.aspx)
- [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633506.aspx)